# missing typedef in header file causes compile error

Tags: c++, typedef

I have a header file monitor.hpp with:

```
#ifndef MONITOR_HPP_
#define MONITOR_HPP_

typedef unsigned short abc_status_id_t;

struct monitor_update
{
    monitor_update(BYTE* data, size_t size) { /* implementation */ }
    BYTE* data;
    size_t dataSize;
};

class monitor_consumer 
{
public:
    virtual ~monitor_consumer() {};
    virtual void updated(const monitor_update& update) = 0;
};

#endif // MONITOR_HPP_
```

Notice above that there is no typedef for the BYTE - long story - but other files using maybe have included Windows.h or something that would have typedef'd BYTE.

But then I have this class where I need to #include that header file:

```
#ifndef BYTE
typedef unsigned char       BYTE;
#endif

#include "monitor.hpp"

class mymonitor  : public monitor_consumer 
{
public:
    void updated(const monitor_update& update) { }
};

int main() {

}
```

If I comment out the #ifndef BYTE then I get:

```
monitor.hpp(9): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'BYTE'
monitor.hpp(10): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
monitor.hpp(10): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

The define fix works and I don't get any problems compiling and linking.  But is it the best approach.  What other options do I have?

Comment: other files may have defined BYTE but they are not included in monitor.hpp. This will cause problem

Comment: Use `std::uint8_t`. Solved.

Comment: There is a conceptual problem in the code, and that may be causing part of the confusion. typedef is a compiler directive, while #ifndef is a pre-compiler directive. Typedef will always be out of the scope of the pre-compiler

Comment: @LogicStuff - only solved if there is a requirement that the code should not compile on systems that don't have a native 8-bit type. `std::uint_least8_t` or `std::uint_fast8_t` is more portable and usually more appropriate.

Comment: @JorgeTorres Are you saying that if I have typedef int aaa; in some other compiled header and I use #ifndef aaa then the code after #ifndef will never be entered?

Comment: @JorgeTorres Reason I am querying is because I have no #define BYTE in any headers but I do have a typedef unsigned char BYTE; in another hdr and above fix works.

Comment: @Angus Comber Hi, If you have a "typedef BYTE" in another header the #ifndef will not see that as a defined type for the pre-processor. So I guess that what you are doing there is checking if no headers define BYTE in the pre-processor, and they you define it yourself.Have you checked. I would check with
#ifdef BYTE
#warning "BYTE already defined"
#endif

That if you are un a gnu compiler. For microsoft you can use #pragma message() instead of #warning. In this way you will find out if another header defined somehow BYTE earlier for the preprocessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if some of the headers you are using do a `#define BYTE <something>`, which is a fairly unfriendly thing to do.

You could try to find out if it is possible to remove or disable that `#define` (some Windows headers allow you to selectively turn off parts of them).

Otherwise your solution is a reasonable way of coping with a hostile environment. An alternative would be

```
#undef BYTE
typedef unsigned char       BYTE;
```